# How to use Apache Cassandra with Kaa?

Tags: cassandra, kaa

I want to store sensor data from my Raspberry Pi using Kaa and Cassandra. I tried following the instructions for the Cassandra Demo and when I type in the commands:

```
cqlsh
use kaa;
```

This error message appears:

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace 'kaa' does not exist"

But kaa does exist as a Keyspace in the Cassandra Demo in the Kaa Sandbox.

Is there something else I need to do to make Cassandra recognize that 'kaa' does exist (and link it to that specific application)?

Comment: make sure that it is case sensitive from both keyspace and code end .

Comment: It is all lowercase in both the Kaa Sandbox GUI, and when I type in the command in the Kaa Sandbox command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Cassandra cqlsh:

```
sudo cqlsh -f /etc/kaa-node/conf/cassandra.cql
```

(mentioned in the [single node setup](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/))

Comment: The database and tables do appear now, but they are still empty after I re-run the program.

Comment: Did you add a Cassandra log appender correctly?
Be careful with the column mapping. - The first time I tried myself the data was not inserted as the mapping was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next solution:

1. enter `cqlsh` on Kaa Sandbox
2. execute `cqlsh> SOURCE '/usr/lib/kaa-node/conf/cassandra.cql';`
3. check if keyspace has appeared `cqlsh> DESCRIBE keyspaces;` If everything ok you should see `kaa` keyspace among others.

Also, it would be great if you provide some information about Kaa Sandbox. You can see such info in the bottom of Sandbox UI (default port is 9080).

Comment: It is listed there now, thank you. But the tables I would expect to be there are not there. The example has the tables; sensor_per_row, sensor_per_date, and sensor_per_region. But when I list the tables I see 14 other tables that I was not expecting. Do I have to create the tables here manually?

Comment: All tables are constructed during log appender initialization, since they are already there you can go on admin UI (port 8080) `->Cassandra data analytics demo -> Log appenders` edit (for example change its name) and save it. As a result corresponding tables will appear in kaa keyspace.

Comment: Thank you, they do appear now, but they are still empty after I re-run the program.